# prevent backup from running in parallel

Tags: rsync, backup

In my script `/usr/local/bin/backup`, that I call every hour from `/etc/crontab`, I use *rsync* to copy data to an off-site server.
That all worked fine, even in cases where we had somewhat more new data than can be pushed out in an hour.

Last week someone copied an 11GB file on the data partition and when I found out the next day there were 14 rsync programs running in parallel, each of then getting no bandwidth and each probably working on the same huge file. I killed them all (before realising I should have kept the first one running), stopped the cron job and ran the backup script by hand.

I can write out a file in the script before starting rsync and check in the script if that file is already there to prevent backup from running in parallel. Is there an easier way of doing this?

My `/etc/crontab` entry:

```
5  *  *  *  *   root  /usr/local/bin/backup
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are different ways of doing this, but IMO the easiest is inserting [flock](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/flock.1.html) before the command in the crontab file:

```
5  *  *  *  *   root  flock -n /var/lock/backup /usr/local/bin/backup
```

The `/var/lock/backup` file is the lock that flock uses and `-n` immediately makes the command fail if the lock already exists.

This could of course mean that if one backup takes 1 hour and 1 minute, that the next one starts 59 minutes later. If that is a problem you could look into using `-x`.

Comment: Isn't `-c` required?

Comment: It is certainly not required and as I read the man page, you cannot have arguments to your command if you use `-c`, see the updated link to the man page

Answer (score 1):

On a recent OpenBSD installation (OpenBSD 6.7, since snapshots Apr 16 2020), you may use the optional `-s` option in the schedule itself to avoid overlapping instances of a job:

```
5 * * * * root -s /usr/local/bin/backup
```

or, in the root user's own crontab,

```
5 * * * * -s /usr/local/bin/backup
```

From the [OpenBSD `crontab(5)` manual](https://man.openbsd.org/crontab.5):

> Commands may be modified as follows:
>
> [...]
>
> `-s command`
>       Only a single instance of `command` will be run concurrently. Additional instances of `command` will not be scheduled until the earlier one completes.